# Java - ¿Como recorrer un archivo.txt y ordenarlo?

Tags: java, archivo, ordenamiento

Buen dia a todos y gracias por responder. Estoy haciendo un programa en que se maneja un archivo.txt, es una agenda telefonica que guarda el nombre apellidos y el telefono de la persona sin embargo no tengo idea de como hacer que dicha agenda ordene alfabeticamente los datos que estan dentro del archivo que yo llene previamente. o como poner un limite a los datos que podemos guardar. ¡ayuda!

Están guardados así:

```
marian # jaimes # garcia # 78945631   
pedro # estrada # lopez # 7451365898   
lady # ayala # peres # 13546789    
susana # gomez # corona # 123456   
guillermo  # guadarrama # sanchez # 7894563
```

¿como ordenarlos? disculpen soy muy novato en todo esto.

Comment: ¡hola! Comparte por favor el código que tienes actualmente

Comment: Hola @RaymundoEstrada. ¿Qué es lo que has intentado? Tenemos que ver lo que has probado para ver donde tienes algún fallo. Te recomiendo que leas [tour] y [ask] para poder rehacer tu pregunta y que sea mejor aceptada en este sitio.

Comment: La interfaz Comparable y la clase Collections son tus amigas.

Comment: Dí si cada linea corresponde a una entrada. Si es así, como quieres ordenarlos? Es decir, ordenarás por nombre o apellido ó por el número que sale al final?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void ordenarFichero(String rutaAlFichero) throws IOException{
    Path path = Paths.get(rutaAlFichero);
    List<String> lineas = Files.readAllLines(path);
    lineas = lineas.stream()
                    .sorted((o1,o2)->o1.compareTo(o2))//Aquí podrías poner un criterio de ordenación diferente
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```